# facing issues with scroll bars in Jqgrid grouping option

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I am using JQGrid grouping functionality and it works well with IE8 and above and all browsers. On load of the grid i am colapsing the grid using `groupCollapse : false`. But in IE6, i am facing the problem with the scroll bars. please see the following screen shot

![Grid in IE6][1]

use the following  link for the image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSfTx.png

Comment: The problem seems not fatal. Sorry, but are IE6 really important enough today to invest the time to support it?